# How to route all the subdomain to the same folder in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I am hosting a website on AWS EC2, I do want all the subdomain of the website to point on the same folder ie /var/www/html/laravel/public as shown below: How to achieve it ? I tried it by putting wildcard in front of server_name, *.example.com, but it does not works. How to achieve the same ?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    . . .

    root /var/www/html/laravel/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name example.com www.example.com *.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    . . .
}
```

Comment: Does the desired subdomain, which I think looks something like `www.example.subdomain.com` render the same content as `www.example.com`? Because you usually need to register to be able to use wildcard DNS.

Comment: They both render the same content. I need to capture the sub domain name  for some internal logic that's the only reason I want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `*.domain.com` Like :

```
<VirtualHost 111.222.33.4>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This would cause the Virtualhost to be used for all subdomains that don't have Virtualhosts.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following using test as our site

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@test.com
    DocumentRoot /home/test/public/
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@subdomain.test.com
    DocumentRoot /home/test/public/
    ServerName subdomain.test.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.test.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The above is a sample for a single subdomain namely "subdomain". For all subdomain use the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@subdomain.test.com
    DocumentRoot /home/test/public/
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias *.test.com
</VirtualHost>
```